# Word 2007 not opening blank page

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

When I start Word or create a new document, it has the text of an old document in it. I do not know what to do? I need help please. I have tried deleting the file but it is still opening

Answer (score 1):

As per [Microsoft](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/word-help/change-the-normal-template-normal-dotm-HA010030756.aspx), the normal.dotm file is the template file used by Word to create new document. This is so you can choose your own default fonts, page layout, and so on. Note that it is not .doc or .docx, which are the regular document types for Word for documents you have created. This is probably why deleting the old document didn't work, as they are completely different files in different locations.

As per [this article](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2387066,00.asp), close Word completely, then use Windows explorer to go to %appdata%\Microsoft\Templates. If you type that into the Windows Explorer address bar, it will take you to your own settings on your computer. Inside this folder, delete the normal.dotm file. The next time you restart Word it will create a new, blank normal.dotm file to use as the default.

The Microsoft article has more detail on how to make additional customizations, if you do want them.